# Use of deleted function 'QObject::QObject(const QObject&)'

Tags: c++, qt, классы, qt5

Ругается на класс, не могу понять причины:

```
#ifndef SETMAIL_H
#define SETMAIL_H

#include <QObject>
#include "class_mail/_class_mail.h"

class SetMail : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit SetMail(QObject *parent = 0);

  QString sender;       // кому
  QString provider;     // от кого
  QString theme;        // тема письма
  QString file_letter;  // тело письма
  QString file_attach;  // приложенжие к письму
  int subscribeId;      // id подписки

signals:

public slots:

private:
  void test ();
};

#endif // SETMAIL_H

#include "setmail.h"

SetMail::SetMail(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void SetMail::test()
{
 subscribeId = 0;
}
```

Ошибки:

```
error: use of deleted function 'SetMail::SetMail(const SetMail&)'
         case 0: _t->setMail((*reinterpret_cast< SetMail(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
                                                                    ^
/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:461: error: 'QObject::QObject(const QObject&)' is private
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(QObject)
                    ^
error: within this context
 class SetMail : public QObject
       ^
error: use of deleted function 'QObject::QObject(const QObject&)'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для объектов унаследованных от `QObject` не генерируется конструктор копирования и оператор копирующего присваивания, потому что они отключены в `QObject` при помощи макроса `Q_DISABLE_COPY`
Например:

```
class A : public QObject{
};
void foo(){
    A a1;
    A a2 = a1; //Ошибка
    A a3;
    a3 = a1;   //Ошибка
}
```

Есть два пути решения проблемы. Первый заключается в том, чтобы написать самому недостающие методы:

```
class A : public QObject{
public:
    A(const A &other):
        QObject(other.parent())
    {}
    A& operator=(const A &other){
        return *this;
    }
};
void foo(){
    A a1;
    A a2 = a1; //Работает
    A a3;
    a3 = a1;   //Работает
}
```

Правда в этом случае копия объекта не будет иметь всех сигнально-слотовых соединений

Второй предполагает избегать копирования и использовать указатели

```
class A : public QObject{
};
void foo(QObject *parent){
    A *a1 = new A(parent);
    A *a2 = a1;            //Работает
    A *a3 = new A(parent);
    a3 = a1;               //Работает
}
```

**UPD:** Для вашего класса получится что-то такое:

```
class SetMail : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QString sender;
    QString provider;
    QString theme;
    QString file_letter;
    QString file_attach;
    int subscribeId;

    explicit SetMail(QObject *parent = 0):
        QObject(parent)
    {}

    SetMail(const SetMail &other):
        QObject(other.parent()),
        sender(other.sender),
        provider(other.provider),
        theme(other.theme),
        file_letter(other.file_letter),
        file_attach(other.file_attach),
        subscribeId(other.subscribeId)
    {}
    SetMail& operator=(const SetMail &other){
        sender = other.sender;
        provider = other.provider;
        theme = other.theme;
        file_letter = other.file_letter;
        file_attach = other.file_attach;
        subscribeId = other.subscribeId;
    }

    //...
};
```

Comment: Добавил: 
      SetMail(const SetMail &other):
          QObject(other.parent())
      {}
      SetMail& operator=(const SetMail &other){
          return *this;
      } 
    
    Выдало ошибки: 
    /moc_mainwindow.cpp:106: error: undefined reference to `MainWindow::providerNOW()'
    
    Ругается на:
    case 7: _t->providerNOW(); break;
    :-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Можно ли указать решение на моём примере?

Comment: @shaman888, линковщик не может найти реализацию метода `providerNOW()`. Кстати, раз дело дошло до ликовки, это означает что предыдущую ошибку мы исправили.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Добавил реализацию слота providerNOW() ошибка исчезла, ваш вариант зачту, но хотелось бы видеть в ответе реализацию моего примера.

Comment: @shaman888, обновил